# use vtk in pycharm ,python3.9.2 conda

Tags: vtk

I want to run the python+vtk in pycharm by using conda，there are some errors in my computer，please help me.

```
import vtkmodules.all as vtk
from vtkmodules.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor
```

```
  File "D:\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import vtkmodules.all as vtk
  File "C:\Users\86136\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\vtkmodules\all.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .vtkCommonCore import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing vtkCommonCore: 找不到指定的模块。
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I frequently met the similar problem for `Qt`, and I can not find a good solution. Usually, I create a new conda environment or re-install conda.